# How to access updated files from job 1 to job 2 azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have 1 azure build pipeline for my Xunit azure repository, which is having 2 jobs,
First job runs .cs file which will update an json file (customerdata.json) . Is there any way to read this file in second job and send SQS message. This might be old question but I'm new azure pipeline, so not sure about how to write yaml for this.
Also I am using self host agent pool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that by publishing the build artifacts (`task: PublishBuildArtifacts`) at the end of the `job 1` and downloading them at the beginning of `job 2` (`task: DownloadBuildArtifacts`).

```
[...]
- job: 
  steps:
    [...]
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s/path-to/customerdata.json'
        ArtifactName: 'customerdata'
        publishLocation: 'Container'
- job:
  steps:
    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
      inputs:
        buildType: 'current'
        downloadType: 'single'
        artifactName: 'customerdata'
        downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)' #Path where to download the artifact
    [...]
```

Comment: Thanks @LJ. And how to read the file from downloaded artifacts? Or add how to add it into variable . As I need to send this file in next task that is for SQS message trigger.

Comment: You can read & send it the same way you would usually. To make it more simple, you can just replace the non-updated file with an updated file from the artifact by changing the `downloadPath` to `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s/path-to/customerdata.json` (the same path you used in `PublishBuildArtifacts@1` task. (Just keep in mind you might have to add a script line that removes the original file before artifact download, depending on what agent you are using to avoid conflicts).